# How to insert data in different schema other than public schema in database. [LARAVEL]

Tags: php, database, laravel, eloquent, migration

I want to insert data in the schema i created in laravel migration but i couldn't find a way.

Can anyone please guide ?

```
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS reports');

    Schema::create('reports.campaign_reports', function (Blueprint $table) 
     {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('campaign')->nullable();
        $table->string('currency')->nullable();
    });
}
```

This is my model:

```
class CampaignReport extends Model
{

//    protected $connection = 'schema.reports';

protected $table = 'campaign_reports';

protected $fillable = [
    'campaign',
    'currency'
    ];
}
```

And this is how i am saving:

```
CampaignReport::create((array) $dataObject);
```

I am getting this error:

> SQLSTATE[42P01]: Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "campaign_reports" does not exist LINE 1: insert into "campaign_reports" ("campaign", "currency",...

[image]

Comment: you want to store data manually or user inputs ?

Comment: I am hitting google ads api and its returning me data. I am not working with forms or user inputs. Just want to store data coming from that request. it was working when i was in public scheme (default way) but now i want to store in different schema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try defining a second database connection in your database config:

```php
/** config/database.php */

// ...

  'connections' => [

        'public_schema' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            // ...
            'schema' => 'public',
        ],

        'reports_shema' => [
            'driver' => 'pgsql',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE'),
            // ...
            'schema' => 'reports',
        ],
    ],

// ...
```

Then, set the connection in your model (this is useful to do Eloquent/Query Builder operations):

```php
class CampaignReport extends Model
{

    protected $connection = 'reports_schema'; // <----

    protected $table = 'campaign_reports';

    protected $fillable = [
            'campaign',
            'currency'
        ];

    // ...
}
```

Of course, when you make your migration that needs to be run in a different connection than the default, you have to specify it:

```php
public function up()
{
    DB::statement('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS reports');

    Schema::connection('reports_schema')->create('campaign_reports', function (Blueprint $t)
#           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
     {
        $t->bigIncrements('id');
        $t->string('campaign')->nullable();
        $t->string('currency')->nullable();
    });
}
```

Btw, update your `.env` default database key to this:

```php
DB_CONNECTION=public_schema
```

Comment: but then what should i give in my env file? right now it is DB_CONNECTION = pgsql

Comment: This is because Laravel need a default connection to use whenever isn't specified. In your migration you ran if using the default conecction that uses the `public` schema, I think that is where the error is originated.

Comment: Btw, in your `.env`: `DB_CONNECTION = public_schema'`

Comment: Well i added things in `database.php` and migrations and model, but i got this error:  `InvalidArgumentException  : Database [reports_schema] not configured.`

Comment: @Mohsin the databases names needs to be the same, that's why I used `EVN('DB_DATABASE')` in both

Comment: damn it was missing 'c' in reports_schema in `database.php` now its migrated. ill try insertion now.

Comment: Glad to help. Have a nice day.